# Check all input fields have been filled out with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 divs, each with a dfew input fields and next button on. 
I want to write a snippet of jQuery that when the next button is clicked it checks to ensure all input fields WITHIN the same div as the button, are not null.

I've tried the following with no luck but Im 100% certain its wrong, only I cant find the relevant information online...

http://jsfiddle.net/xG2KS/1/

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You could use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce the set of all `input` elements to only those that are empty, and check the `length` property of what remains:

```
$(".next").click(function() {
    var empty = $(this).parent().find("input").filter(function() {
        return this.value === "";
    });
    if(empty.length) {
        //At least one input is empty
    }
});
```

Note that the definition of empty in the above code is an empty string. If you want to treat blank spaces as empty too, you may want to trim the value before comparing.

Also note that there is no need to pass `this` into jQuery inside the `filter` function. The DOM element itself will have a `value` property, and it's much faster to access that instead of using `val`.

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xG2KS/15/).

Comment: How can use this with a form with input text and select?

Answer (score 8):

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    var emptyInputs = $(this).parent().find('input[type="text"]').filter(function() { return $(this).val() == ""; });
    if (emptyInputs.length) {
        alert('Fail!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @garvey!, is there a way to say, if ANY input is empty throw one alert as oppposed to looping?

Comment: How can I inclue selects too??

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no jQuery selector for this case you can extend jQuery’s selector capabilities.

Assuming you select all [:text](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/) elements, the extension is:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
     isEmpty: function(e) {
         return e.value === '';
     }
});
```

Hence, you can select all empty text fields:

```
$(this).closest('div').find(':text:isEmpty');
```

```js
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  isEmpty: function (e) {
      return e.value === '';
  }
});
$('.next').click(function () {
      var missingRequired = $(this).closest('div').find(':text:isEmpty');
  console.log('Empty text fields: ' + missingRequired.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="next" class="next" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="next" class="next"  />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="next" class="next"  />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    var inputs = $(this).parent().find('input[value=""]');
    if (!inputs.length) {
        // you have empty fields if this section is reached
    }
});
```

Comment: This will say there are empty inputs even if there are none, because it looks at the `value` *attribute* rather than the property.

Comment: I don't follow? As I'm not as well versed in jQuery as I should be, would you mind explaining?

Comment: You've used an attribute selector to find elements whose `value` attribute is equal to the empty string. The `value` *attribute* is what is defined on the element itself: `<input type='text' value='something'>`. Since none of the `input` elements in question have a `value` attribute, your code will always say they are all empty.