# PHP: How to make the user stay on the same page if the required fields in the form aren't filled?

Tags: php, forms, redirect, location

How can I make the user stay on the same page if the required fields in the form aren't filled? Any answer would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php 
header('Location: COMING SOON.html');
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['last_name'];
$cons = $_POST['cons'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$recipient = "pixiedustmed@yahoo.com";

$to = 'pixiedustmed@yahoo.com';

$subject = "Contact Message from: $name $surname - $email";

$headers = "From: $name $surname \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: avedis@avedis.ga\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<div class="about-center"><h1 style="font-family: Lato-Light; font-size: 2em">You have received a contact message from Your website.</h1></div>';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666; font-family: Segoe UI; font-size: 16px;" cellpadding="12">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><p style='color: #2c3e50; font-weight:bold'>Name: </p> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['name']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><p style='color: #2c3e50; font-weight:bold'>Surname: </p> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['last_name']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><p style='color: #2c3e50; font-weight:bold'>Email: </p> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #71bdf4;'><td><p style='color: #ffffff'>Message: </p> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['message']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #34495e;'><td><p style='color: #ffffff'>Consultation Info: </p> </td><td style='color: #ffffff'>" . strip_tags($_POST['cons']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><p style='color: #2c3e50; font-weight:bold'>Password: </p> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['pass']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= '<br><h1 style="font-family: Lato-Light; font-size: 14px; color:#c0392b;"><a href="http://avedis.ga">Click here to open avedis.ga</a></h1>';
$message .= '<h1 style="font-family: Segoe UI; font-size: 13px; color:#eee;">This is an autogenerated message designed by S.G.</h1>';
$message .= '<div class="about-center">-</div>';
$message .= "</body></html>";


mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers, $password) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

So, as you see, I have put `header('Location: COMING SOON.html');` which evantually works.
Plus, in my css, I have put a `required=""` field which didn't let the user click the submit button and displayed a message. But now that I put a header, the `PHP` disregards everything.

My site can be accessed by [clicking here](http://avedis.ga/); scroll down to the end of the page and try in the contact form, and. Let me know what you think about the design and all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(empty($name) || empty($surname) || empty($cons) || empty($password) || empty($email) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($message)){
    // do something if a field is empty
} else {
    // do something if fields are all filled
}
```

Put this after you declare the variables like `$name`, `$surname`, and `$cons`.

Comment: Thank you! But... how can I make the user stay on the same page when the fields are empty.

Comment: I mean when the fields are empty, I don't want anything to happen!

Comment: Then put the header function under the comment "// do something if fields are all filled"

Answer (score 0):

Use some javascript to ensure that the user has filled all the fields, or just include the php inside the index page and if the user has filled all the forms send the mail, otherwise show an error around the unfilled fields.

Example using jQuery: [Check all input fields have been filled out with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907835/check-all-input-fields-have-been-filled-out-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You should check and validate the feilds first and if the feilds are correctly submitted, then only u should redirect the user using the header().

ps: what you asked was actually not clear.

Hope it helps thankz!