# How to alert user for blank form fields?

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I have this form that has 3 inputs and when a user leaves a field blank a dialogue box pops up to alert the user a field is blank.  The code I have below only works for 2 specific input.  When i try adding another input to the code it doesnt work.  It only works for 2 inputs.  How can I make it work for all three?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function val(){
    var missingFields = false;
    var strFields = "";
    var mileage=document.getElementById("mile").value;
    var location=document.getElementById("loc").value;




    if(mileage=='' || isNaN(mileage))
    {
    missingFields = true;
    strFields += "     Your Google Map's mileage\n";
    }

   if(location=='' )
    {
    missingFields = true;
    strFields += "     Your business name\n";
    }




    if( missingFields ) {
        alert( "I'm sorry, but you must provide the following field(s) before continuing:\n" + strFields );
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing 3 alerts may be disturbing, use something like this:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {
    var empty = $(this).find('input[type=text]').filter(function() {
        return $.trim(this.value) === "";
    });
    if(empty.length) {
        alert('Please fill in all the fields');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907835/check-all-input-fields-have-been-filled-out-with-jquery).

Or you can do validation for each field this way using HTML [data attributes](http://www.learningjquery.com/2011/09/using-jquerys-data-apis/):

```
<form data-alert="You must provide:" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="one" data-alert="Your Google Map's mileage" />
    <input type="text" id="two" data-alert="Your business name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

... combined with jQuery:

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    var thisForm = $(this);
    var thisAlert = thisForm.data('alert');
    var canSubmit = true;
    thisForm.find('input[type=text]').each(function(i) {
        var thisInput = $(this);
        if ( !$.trim(thisInput.val()) ) {
            thisAlert += '\n' + thisInput.data('alert');
            canSubmit = false;
        };
    });
    if( !canSubmit ) {
        alert( thisAlert );
        return false;
    }
});
```

Take a look at this script [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/zkxt5vxo/).

Of course, you can select/check only input elements that have attribute `data-alert` (which means they are required). [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zkxt5vxo/1/) with mixed input elements.

Comment: im looking for a way to specify which field is left blank

Answer (score 0):

You can add the *required* tag in the input fields. No jQuery needed.

```html
<input required type="text" name="name"/>
```

Comment: As a tip, you should also use a polyfill for `required`. Something like [h5validate](http://www.html5-tutorials.org/form-validation/polyfills-for-form-validation/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var fields = ["a", "b", "c"]; // "a" is your "mile"
var empties= [];

for(var i=0; i<fields.length; i++)
{
    if(!$('#'+fields[i]).val().trim())
        empties.push(fields[i]);
}

if(empties.length)
{
    alert('you must enter the following fields '+empties.join(', '));
    return false;
}
else
    return true;
```

instead of this

```
var name = $('#mile').val();
if (!name.trim()) {
    alert('you must enter in your mile');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i need a way to specify which fields are left blank

Comment: I am assuming the id of the field is descriptive enough.

Comment: i mean to specify in the alert box which fields are left blank