# How To Check All The Textbox Of Div Are Full Or Not in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check all the textbox of a div are empty or not in jQuery

```
<div id="compWord">
<input id="c" ondrop="dropabc(event)" class="box ui-droppable" type="textbox">
<input id="c" ondrop="dropabc(event)" class="box ui-droppable" type="textbox">
<input id="c" ondrop="dropabc(event)" class="box ui-droppable" type="textbox">
</div>
```

I want to check all the div either they are empty or either they are full i need the selector for both of them

Comment: full means what? Has a value?

Comment: @epascarello I want to check all the div whether they have value or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907835/check-all-input-fields-have-been-filled-out-with-jquery

Comment: first to mention that, using the same `id` for all fields is not a good coding practice.do you want to check this in a button click

Comment: Note that: 1. You can not use the same `id="c"` for multiple inputs.  2. There is no `type="textbox"` do you mean `type="text"`?  3. You say "all the div are full" - what? Do you mean all the text inputs? 4. **Important**: You have to show your jQuery code for anyone to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#element').is(':empty')){
  //do something
}
```

Use above code to check element is empty or not.

Comment: this selector is only for one i want to check all the textbox

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in so many ways, this is a very basic way of doing this as your request. try this small demo. 
**note : please do not use same id for all elements.**

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="compWord">
 <input id="box0" class="box ui-droppable" type="textbox"> 
 <input id="box1" class="box ui-droppable" type="textbox">
 <input id="box2" class="box ui-droppable" type="textbox">
 <input type="button" id="checkyou" value="enter">
</div>
<h3 style="color:red;display:none;" id="warnme">You hava to fill all fields</h3>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 
$("#checkyou").click(function(){
 for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
   var theId = "box"+i;
   var textval = $("#"+theId).val();
   alert(textval);// I put an alert to show you what is the value remove this if you do not want

   if (textval == "") 
   {
    $("#warnme").show();
   }
   else
   {
    $("#warnme").hide();
   }
   
  }
});
 

</script>

</html>
```

hope this will help to you.thank you very much.