# Check if all inputs of class have value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class `.address` added to a couple of my inputs. Basically, I want to check if all of them have been filled out. I know this is possible by iterating over the class like this:

```
var valueForAll = true;
$('.address').each(function (i, obj) {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        valueForAll = false;
    }
});
if (valueForAll == true) {
    // Do something
}
else {
    // Do something else
}
```

I don't think this is an ideal solution though. So I found the `:empty` selector. Which works like this:

```
$("input:empty").length == 0;
```

However, doing this for my class always shows a length of 6. I don't know why.

```
$(".address:empty").length == 0;
```

**Edit:**

This is not a duplicate question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907835/check-all-input-fields-have-been-filled-out-with-jquery) attached from @chrispbacon. This question focuses on how to check if all inputs **of a class** have been filled, **not all elements inside a div**. I cannot find any thread on Stack Overflow that focuses on how to check if all inputs have a value of a class without iterating over the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

```
:empty
```

Is used to find elements that have no children.  Not for inputs that do not have a value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:blank

```
:blank
```

Is an up and coming pseudoselector for empty inputs, but coverage is still being added for browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please reopen my question, as this is not a duplicate. See my edit explaining my reasoning.

Comment: Unfortunately, it has to work in all browsers. Can you think of any other way of checking if all inputs of a class have a value without iteration?

Comment: The duplicate does cover your case.  A filter on the inputs would also do the same thing.  `$('input').filter(function(){ return !this.value.trim(); }) === 0`

Comment: I don't need it on all my inputs. I need it only on the inputs inside the class.

Comment: So select just the ones you want to check.  That is a small detail.